# Separating dataset points from void in 3D space

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, set

There is a data set $XYZ$ in MATLAB:

https://dropmefiles.com/INaBP

Using the commands, we will construct points in three-dimensional space:

```
plot3(X,Y,Z,'o')
grid on
daspect([1 1 1])
```

[image]

We can see that the points are collected in "heaps" separated by space.

**Problem:** can these datasets = "heaps" be separated by an approximate boundary from space? This boundary can either describe analytically or simply represent some kind of graphics.

*I am using MATLAB R2019a.*

Comment: The word you are looking for is "clustering". There are many, many algorithms to do this, and matlab comes with some of them available to you. Have a try, google "matlab clustering" and let us know here if you have a problem with them

Comment: @AnderBiguri I found several commands, https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/boundary.html and https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/alphashape.html, but they all showed poor performance. For example, they glue clusters together in some cases. Maybe there are some simpler options, for example, converting a set of points into a smooth and transparent surface?

Comment: None of those functions are clustering functions, so unfortunately you found the wrong thing. MATLAB has a very nice tutorial for you, found, as I said, googling "clustering matlab": https://uk.mathworks.com/discovery/cluster-analysis.html

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thank you for activating the learning process! After reviewing the proposed materials, I decided that a Gaussian mixture and k-means clustering could be suitable for the task. Unfortunately, both methods failed. In the first case, it is required to determine the number of Gaussian distributions to cover a given area, but MATLAB refused to consider their number greater than 2. In the second case, the algorithm cannot separate voids from the data cloud and perceives them as part of a cluster, dividing by points of greatest concentration data.

Comment: @AnderBiguri https://ibb.co/KmjbLMc what do you think about clustering alternatives? i tried to find a smooth point cloud representation, but unfortunately my search results are not successful

Comment: The answer is hard. Clustering is an active research topic (e.g. most state of ar machine learnign methods are for clustering/classification) so it is really hard to give you an answer of what can or can not work. K-means is what I would have tried, yes.